# What is the impact of micro-G environment and magnetic field in LEO on blood flow and brain function?

Tags: microgravity, health, medical, magnetic-field, pressure-gradient-loss

How are sleeping and cognition in microgravity, with rapid changes in magnetic field, different from the normal human life on Earth?

Comment: Speaking only about the magnetic field changes: I'd seriously doubt the magnetic field of the Earth is going to effect a sleeping human, or an awake human. The Earths magnetic field is pretty weak. You can grab a fridge magnet that's stronger.